Existence of prime ideals with given splitting in biquadratic extensions
Let $F$ be a number field, let $L=F(\sqrt{\alpha_1},\sqrt{\alpha_2})$ be a biquadratic extension of $F$ (so $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ are not squares in $F$)
Does there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_F$ such that:

$\mathfrak{p}$ does not divide $2\alpha_1$

$\mathfrak{p}$ is inert in $F(\sqrt{\alpha_1})$

$\mathfrak{p}$ splits in $F(\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2})$ ?


Moreover, if at least one such a $\mathfrak{p}$ exists, are there infinitely many ?
I am happy to assume that the quaternion $F$-algebra $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ does not split, if necessary.
Chebotarev's density theorem does not seem to help, since a prime ideal which splits in $F(\sqrt{\alpha_1})$  and stays inert in $F(\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2})$ gives rise in general to the same factorisation pattern of $f=X^4-2(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)X^2+(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2$ (the splitting field of $f$ is $L$).

What version of Chebotarev are you using? You're looking for Frobenius elements $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ that act trivially on $\sqrt{\alpha_1\alpha_2}$ and non-trivially on $\sqrt{\alpha_1}$. If you identify $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)\simeq\mathrm{Gal}(F(\sqrt{\alpha_1})/F)\times\mathrm{Gal}(F(\sqrt{\alpha_2})/F)$, this is just primes whose Frobenius element is $(-1, -1)$ of which there are infinitely many by Chebotarev. The set you said you couldn't distinguish has Frobenius elements mapping to $(1, -1)$.
